# Assign Random Order to 10000+ records

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to assign a defined random order to a table of over 10000+ records. I have a function utilizing a start date and adding 1 second to each consecutive date, assigned randomly. Then I could sort by the random assigned date. My function worked fine with 50 records, but fails with 10000+ records.

It sets correct dates for about 9000 records, but 1146 records get assigned 0 (1969-12-31 19:00:00) Any help getting this or something similar to work would be appreciated.

```
function randomize(){
  $count = $this->Application->find('count');
  $order = range(0, $count-1); // Array of numbers 0 to count-1
  $startDate = strtotime('December 13, 2011 0:00:00');
  shuffle($order); // scramble array of numbers
  $Applications = $this->Application->find('all');
  set_time_limit(0);
  foreach($Applications as $app){
    $this->Application->id = $app['Application']['id'];
    $this->Application->saveField('order', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $startDate + $order[$this->Application->id]));
  }
  set_time_limit(30);
}
```

Update: I am using MySQL database but need a permanent state for 1 randomization, not repeated randomization as per ORDER BY RAND(). I also updated the code (see above) to reduce overhead, and increased memory in php.ini from 128M to 256M. With the code change the bad dates are no longer 0 but the same as $startDate indicating it may be an issue with the $order array of numbers.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you would want to use a datetime field to order the records. Why not just use an incrementing integer?

Comment: It's what the data owners asked for. I don't know why it's what they want, but it's what they want.

Comment: As an aside, you should be able to optimise this further by only returning the `id` in the `find` method. You're not using anything else, so there's no point including it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions:

Are you sure you're using the proper date format there?

Why a start date to randomize? Take the date as a fixed number, as you're doing (X in this case): If you do `X + givenOrderNumber` for each record then the order will be defined by `givenOrderNumber`... so why the unnecessary addition?

I've got the query I understand you're looking for here:

```
set @num = 0;
select *,
  date_add('2011-12-13 00:00:00', interval @num := @num + 1 second) as newOrder
from table1
order by newOrder
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f43b/22)

It sorts the records by a date which is incremented by one each time. Now if you want to use the application id cheat:

```
select *,
  date_add('2011-12-13 00:00:00', interval id second) as newOrder
from table1
order by newOrder
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f43b/24)

However, whether this is useful or not for you... it seems to be unnecessary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, the date format is right, and works for 9324 of the 10570 records. Thanks for the SQL, I was able to modify it to work as I needed.   
    set @num = 0;
    UPDATE `applications` SET `order` = date_add('2011-12-13 00:00:00', interval @num := @num + 1 second)
order by RAND()

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a weird way to do it. Can you tell us which type of database you are using? Some databases like mysql support order random, so you won't need to do all this to get random order...

In MySql is like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY RAND();
```

Also i will listen to juhana comment, Using integers is easier and better done than with dates, you may use bigint if you are going to have a huuuuuge amount of records...

Still i would try to see first if your database supports the random order so you do less work :D

Hope this helps you :D

Comment: While I am using MySQL, a random selection is unique each time. I need a one time randomization of record order, set into a permanent state, which is why I'm storing it into a field.

Comment: @Naidim :Oh i see, thats true. I don't see any mistakes in your code. But you may try to use mt_rand() to generate a int and use that int as the time for each date, that would give you a random order even if a couple of them got the same date the database will choose which one is first :)